# Creating chains of multiple scripts in R

Tags: r, logic

I have three scripts. The first creates my variables, the second executes code, and the third executes code. I would like the first script to run first, and then call the second, which calls the third, which calls the second, etc, until completion.

Example: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3 -> end.

How would I write this in R/RStudio? I'm using `source` in the second and third script but it keeps resourcing the first script and resetting my variables.

Furthermore, how can I run a script from within a script? Is there a `run(script2)` function or something similar in R?

First script:

```
i <- 1

#data creation

i <- 1 #reset variable after data creation
```

Second script:

```
source("C:\\Users\\NK\\Desktop\\Hillman\\FFNN Model Complexity Project\\script1.R") #call first script for variables

#execute code on data

i = i + 1 

source("C:\\Users\\NK\\Desktop\\Hillman\\FFNN Model Complexity Project\\script3.R") #call third script
```

Third script:

```
#run data execution

i = i + 1

if (i == ndata) {stop()    #ndata is max number of runs
} else { #continue the script
  print(i)   
}

source("C:\\Users\\NK\\Desktop\\Hillman\\FFNN Model Complexity Project\\script2.R")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would probably replace "script" with "function" in that description and see what makes sense. If you aren't organizing your code as a `function` yet, then I suggest that is where you should be focusing your efforts.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just not sure how I would go about that. I'm relatively new to programming and I'm not sure how the loop would work as a function (?)

Comment: While I'm sure there are plenty of good tutorials out there, my first recommendation is almost always from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ (specifically http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html in this case).

Comment: Okay I'll read through that, thanks. How can you have one script "run" a second script, however? Not `source`.

Comment: Exactly. Use functions.

Comment: Can I turn the script into a function? Not sure what you mean

Comment: Cherax -- I heartily second the recommendations of @r2evans : Move to thinking in terms of functions rather than thinking in terms of scripts. I'll moreover say that it's impossible for us to help you in this transition as you haven't provided a [mcve] -- we have no idea how to help you think about this since we have no idea what is in your code

Comment: Cherax, this really isn't the best forum for tutorials, and I'm in a distracted-enough state (with the "work" that pays). Learning how to program is not something you're going to get from comments on a forum, it's better suited for tutorials, howtos, and classes. That tutorial link I gave is a reasonable start.

Comment: I really don't think it's a tutorial style question. It's also plenty easy just to provide the answer :)). I provided a repex, although I don't think it is needed.

Comment: Since the second script sources the first, anytime your source it, you'll always be resetting `i`. We don't typically structure R code this way. Normally when we `source()` a file, it is to load functions from that file, not to execute arbitrary code. You can;t have control flow between source contexts, but you can have it between functions. Why are you trying to break up your code like this? What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was training a neural net in a loop (multiple simulations) but my principal investigator told me to rewrite my code such that it was two scripts bouncing off of each other. He wrote this: "At the end of the 1st program, add a line of code that calls program #3 to run. Finish with a line of code in the third program that runs the 2nd program."

Comment: That is a very unusual request/recommendation. I guess I'd probably follow with your PI if that's what they want. But I don't think most R users would make such a design decision in general. Perhaps there is a more specific reason they have that solution in mind that we are not aware of.

Comment: My previous script would generate random data and then train it 500 times in a for loop, but my PI called this slow and instead suggested I do what the post is asking. Honestly, I'm not sure why this inherently speeds up the process, or if it does, but I am working toward implementing it and all that remains is for the scripts to reference themselves. Is there a "run" or "call" function in R that tells one script to run another? Thanks :)

Comment: Please go to your PI with these questions. I can only second what others have said: Use functions. It's a mystery why your PI thinks their proposal would speed up R code (based on my R knowledge, I doubt that very much) but they know your code (in contrast to us)